# why can't we declare object of a class inside the same class?

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
  A a;//why can't we do this
};
```

Comment: What would happen when such a class is instantiated? It would construct an A, which constructs another A, and so on, until the end of time. So, yeah, a constructor that makes a stack overflow isn't a good thing. Oh, yeah, and the instance would have an infinite size.

Comment: It's turtles all the way down.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do

```
class A {
    A* a;
}
```

because it doesn't require knowing the size of A.

Answer (score 24):

Because the class would be infinite in size.

(This is done language-wise by specifying you can't have incomplete types as members, only reference or pointers to them, and that `A` is an incomplete type until the end of the class definition.)

Comment: So what if it is of infinite size?  Memory is cheap nowadays!

Comment: @James: Reminds me of the guy who wanted to write a program that creates every possible word of up to 23 letters and didn't flinch when I told him he'd need over a million TB hard disks for that...

Answer (score 12):

I take it you're coming from Java or something? `A a` will create a full instance of type `A`, which, well, contains `A`, which contains `A`, which contains `A`.

You're probably thinking about this:

```
class A
{
  A *a; // A pointer to A, not a full instance
};
```

Comment: Just wanted to ask the size of `*a`?

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi sizeof(*a) is the size of a pointer, so most likely 4 or 8 bytes depending on your architecture.

Answer (score 8):

```
A a;//why can't we do this
```

Because `A` is an incomplete type, as it has not been defined yet, rather it's being defined. And the compiler needs to know the complete type of `A` when it sees it inside `class A`, and since `A` is incomplete, it **cannot** determine it's size, it **cannot** determine how much space the member variable `a` is going to take, therefore it will not compile it.

But since size of a pointer is well-known to the compiler, no matter what type of pointer it is. You can define a pointer in your class like this:

```
class A
{
    A *pA; //okay since sizeof(pA) == sizeof(void*) == well-known to the compiler!
};
```

Online Demo : http://www.ideone.com/oS5Ir

Answer (score 3):

In C++ :
       You can not do this, As it will be recursive structure (no end for calculating object size) , to Overcome this problem,
Use Self Referential Pointer i.e. the Pointer having the address of Same class type.

```
class A
{
    A* aObj; // Self Referential Pointer
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way you can have a pointer to object of class A and this way it is not required to know the size of class A before it is declared at compile time.

```
class A {
A* a;
};
```