# c++ defining a Node class, which has a private variable of Node (a Node for use in a*)

Tags: c++

I am very new to c++ and i am trying to define a Node class which holds information about another node, in this case the node will be the parent node so i can trace the most optimal route using an A* search.

so far i have tried (node.h file):

```
class node{

    private:
    int xCoord;
    int yCoord;
    int value;
    int hueristicCost;
    int pathCost;
    class node parent;

    public:
    node(int xC, int yC, int value);
    int getXPos();
    int getYPos();
    int getValue();


};
```

But this throws the compilation error:

```
node.h:10:13: error: field ‘parent’ has incomplete type
```

I am probably missing something stupidly obvious, but how would i go about completing this?

Comment: It should probably be a pointer. Otherwise if you were able to instantiate one it would consume infinite memory. Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706129/can-a-c-class-include-itself-as-an-attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A member must be a complete type (as the error message oblivious already tells you). This means that you can´t have a forward declared member.

Notice, that you can already use `node` (as complete type) inside the node class.

However, defining a member of type `node` is still not possible, because this would lead to infinit recursion. Thus you probably want a `node*` if you have a tree-like model. Also notice that `class Foo* member;` is indeed possible. This is the usual solution if you really cant avoid forward declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare an object of a class inside that class.

Possible duplicate: [why can't we declare object of a class inside the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941629/why-cant-we-declare-object-of-a-class-inside-the-same-class)

Instead, you can define a pointer as others have mentioned:

```
node* parent
```

Answer (score 0):

`class node parent;`

should be:

```
node parent;
```

or rather:

```
node* parent;
```

Comment: The class-key is optional; removing it won't make any difference. The second suggestion is (probably) correct, but simply stating it with no explanation doesn't really answer the question.