# Error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Move' / undefined reference to Move::NONE

Tags: c++, class

Please, I don't know why this simple code is rejected.

It give me 2 compilation errors.
Help me please.

I use **Code::Blocks 20.03**

My compiler is **GNU GCC**

**---move.hpp---**

```
class Move {
    public:
        Move();
        Move(int, int);  
    public:
        int from;
        int to;
    
        const static Move NONE = Move(0,-1); //error here
        //undefined reference if I use 
        //const static Move NONE;
};
```

**---move.cpp---**

```
#include "move.hpp"
Move::Move() {
    this->from = 0;
    this->to = 0;
}
Move::Move(int from, int to) {
    this->from = from;
    this->to = to;
}
```

**---main.cpp---**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "move.hpp"

int main(){
    Move move = Move::NONE;//error here
    std::cout << move.from << std::endl;
    std::cout << move.to << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/static-constant-string-class-member .
Either declare the static member inline or define it in the source file instead of the header.
You should include the errors you get in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide an out-of-class definition for the static data member `NONE` in the source file(like move.cpp) which will work because at that point the class is complete as shown below:

**move.hpp**

```
#pragma once 
class Move {
    public:
        Move();
        Move(int, int);  
    public:
        int from;
        int to;
        //declaration for NONE
        const static Move NONE    ;
//------------------------------^^------>no in class initializer here
        
};
```

**move.cpp**

```
#include "move.hpp"
//definition for Move::NONE
const Move Move::NONE = Move(0,-1);

Move::Move() {
    this->from = 0;
    this->to = 0;
}
Move::Move(int from, int to) {
    this->from = from;
    this->to = to;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/n4x8Rwjiv)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution of my problem.
In fact, we can't create an object class reference in class definition because the size of this class is unknown.

[why can't we declare object of a class inside the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941629/why-cant-we-declare-object-of-a-class-inside-the-same-class)

I ve created a namespace (all name in lower case) for do the work.

```
namespace move {
    const static Move NONE;
}
```